# .NET MSBuild Targets AfterTargets=Pack using dotnet build

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild, .net-core, msbuild-task

**UPDATE:**

It seems that adding `dotnet build -v d` a.k.a setting the verbosity to detailed is revealing more details (obviously) about this process

**ORIGINAL:**

Referencing: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/msbuild-targets

I'm using `dotnet build` and my csproj looks like:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
    <GeneratePackageOnBuild>true</GeneratePackageOnBuild>
    <PackageOutputPath>..\packages\</PackageOutputPath>
    <AssemblyVersion>0.1.0</AssemblyVersion>    
  </PropertyGroup>

  <Target Name="CopyPackage" AfterTargets="Pack">
      <Copy
        SourceFiles="$(OutputPath)..\$(PackageId).$(PackageVersion).nupkg"
        DestinationFolder="%USERPROFILE%\.nuget\packages"
      />
  </Target>
  <Target Name="AfterPackMessage" AfterTargets="Pack">
    <Message Text="Copied $(OutputPath)..\$(PackageId).$(PackageVersion).nupkg TO %USERPROFILE%\.nuget\packages" />  
  </Target>
</Project>
```

I'm only seeing this output

```
C:\code\MySolution.net\MyProject.Core (feature-mediator-http)
λ dotnet build
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 15.8.169+g1ccb72aefa for .NET Core
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

  Restore completed in 70.34 ms for C:\code\MySolution.net\MyProject.Core\MyProject.Core.csproj.
  MyProject.Core -> C:\code\MySolution.net\MyProject.Core\bin\Debug\netstandard2.0\MyProject.Core.dll
  Successfully created package 'C:\code\MySolution.net\packages\MyProject.Core.1.0.0.nupkg'.

Build succeeded.
    0 Warning(s)
    0 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:03.68
```

Two issues here:

1) Those `Target`s aren't seeming to be executed

2) `AssemblyVersion` doesn't seem to get applied

`dotnet pack` or `nuget pack` doesn't seem to make a difference

Answer (score 0):

Better use Importance="High" in such cases:

```
<Message Importance="High" Text="your Message"/>
```